# Inverse a matrix $B+\lambda C$, where $\lambda$ is variable.

Tags: matrices, perturbation-theory, matrix-equations

In my research I need to calculate  $\operatorname{Trace}(A^{-1} C)$ where $A$ is given by two large, but sparse, matrices $B$ and $C$ by $A=B+\lambda C$.

I need to do this inversion many times, so I hope that an analytic approximation exists such that I need only invert a few matrices once. $B$ and $C$ are constant but $\lambda$ varies.

If it's helpful, the norm of $B$ is $\approx 2000$ times the norm of $C$, and $\lambda$ will typically be $\approx 400$.

Unfortunately, neither Tr$(B^{-1} C)$ nor Tr$(C^{-1} B)$  are small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can consider is using the Taylor expansion of $f\colon \lambda \mapsto (B + \lambda C)^{-1}$. We have by the chain rule
\begin{align*}
  f'(\lambda) &= D(\cdot)^{-1}(B + \lambda C)[C]\\
         &= -(B+\lambda C)^{-1}C(B+\lambda C)^{-1}\\
  f''(\lambda) &= -2(B + \lambda C)^{-1}C(B + \lambda C)^{-1}C(B+\lambda C)^{-1}
\end{align*}
So 
$$ (B + \lambda C)^{-1} = B^{-1} - B^{-1}CB^{-1}\lambda - B^{-1}CB^{-1}CB^{-1}\lambda^2 + o(\lambda^2) $$
But I don't if this is helpful in your case.

---

You can of course also write $f(\lambda) = \lambda^{-1} (C + \lambda^{-1}B)^{-1}$, giving
$$ (B + \lambda C)^{-1} = \lambda^{-1}C^{-1} - C^{-1}BC^{-1} - C^{-1}BC^{-1}BC^{-1}\lambda + o(\lambda) $$

Comment: That looks good, but for what values of $\lambda$ is it valid? is it only $\lambda < 1$, like a normal Taylor series?

Comment: It depends, I'd say. As I wrote, I do not know, if it is helpful. Just check if the approximation suffices for your nedds.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for my problem, because the terms get bigger.

Comment: Can the same expansion be done, starting with a $C^{-1}$ term instead? That might converge, but I don't know how to do a Taylor Expansion with a matrix.

Comment: @user1412633 I added sth about that.

Comment: Unfortunately neither converge, which I don't understand at all. The trace of $B^{-1}C$ and $C^{-1}B$ are 55 and 1933363950 respectively, so the terms in both expansions just keep growing.